# Joomla 4 form field to select existing joomla article

Tags: xml, templates, joomla

I am looking for a way to include the imprint and privacy articles in my template. I use the standard xml file in my template. The existing [Joomla standard form field types](https://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types/en) do not seem to offer a solution.

If you want to link a single article in the menu, you can already do this.

Can this also be done in the template? Something like this example.

`<field name="linktomyarticle" type="article" label="Select a article" description="link to privacy article" />`

I would be happy if I could get the correct URL back from Joomla. Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: You may like to try asking your question on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution and am posting it here in case anyone else is looking for it. It may be that there would be a faster way, but this one works for me.

Add to templateDetails.xml:

```
        <field
          name="Datenschutzbeitrag" 
          type="sql"
          default="10"
          label="Datenschutzbeitrag auswählen"
          query="SELECT id, title As Datenschutzbeitrag FROM #__content"
          key_field="id"
          />
```

in the index.php you can now get the code as follows:

```
$this->params->get('Datenschutzbeitrag')`
```

The string contains the article ID of the selected article. I have now written a function that returns a correct seo-optimised Joomla path.

Calling the function:

```
<?php echo druckfenstertools::gibLinkvonID($this->params->get('Datenschutzbeitrag')); ?>
```

The php function:

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

class druckfenstertools {

    public static function gibLinkvonID($ArtikelID)
    {
        $db = Factory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            
        // Abfage erstellen für die ID
        $query->select($db->quoteName(array('id','title','catid')));
        $query->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));
        $query->where('id = ' . $db->quote($ArtikelID));
        
        // Query erzeugen
        $db->setQuery($query);

        $LinkObjekt = $db->loadObject();

        return '<a href="' .  Route::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=' . $LinkObjekt->catid . '&id='.$LinkObjekt->id,true) . '" title="' . $LinkObjekt->title . ' öffnen">' . $LinkObjekt->title . '</a>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The [`quoteName()` method](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html#method_quoteName) can receive an array of (column name) values. So you don't need to call it on each individual array element.  Demo [1](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase) and [2](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/15556/12352).

Comment: And you should be calling `quote()` or casting the value to `int` at `$query->where('id = "' . $ArtikelID . '"')` for stability/security.  Or declare the data type as int with `gibLinkvonID(int $ArtikelID)`.